# Unable to troubleshoot ESP32-CAM

Tags: arduino-esp32

Can someone guide me on how to get these 2 boards (ESP32-CAM) and (ESP32-CAM-MB) to work in tandem and not fail with this frustrating error all the time:

I am using Arduino IDE 2.0.3 on a Macbook pro...

No amount of pressing IO and Reset buttons on both boards helped as upload of any code just fails with below msg:

***A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2***

Need guidance to solve this as I went thru multiple forums but none helped in my case...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcrK5.jpg)